# Preventing sysquerymetrics from being created ASE 15.7

Tags: performance, sybase-ase

Can I prevent Sybase ASE 15.7 from creating the sysquerymetrics view for a database upon creation?  And also, if the view is dropped how can it be added later?

Comment: May I ask why??

Comment: We run automated unit tests to ensure the database was built to spec but we have to make a special exception for this view.  Not a serious impact; I'm mostly just curious.  And we will more then likely have a client ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent it to be created, I don't think so, it uses system tables, so even if you could, not wise you could impact other processes that might need those tables.
You can drop it if you desire.

To recreate it, check the installmaster script, it should be there the definition of that view.

Answer (score 1):

QP metrics are always captured in the default group 1 in each respective database and you can access the metrics info using `sysquerymetrics` view.

So I would suggest you to

- backup the metrics using `sp_metrics 'backup'` from the default running group to a backup group
- Then `drop` the metrics using `sp_metrics 'drop', '@gid'`

so to drop all the metrics from the default group 1, you have to run `sp_metrics 'drop', '1'`

As a side note, you can recreate the view using below sql

```
CREATE VIEW sysquerymetrics (
    uid
    ,gid
    ,hashkey
    ,id
    ,sequence
    ,exec_min
    ,exec_max
    ,exec_avg
    ,elap_min
    ,elap_max
    ,elap_avg
    ,lio_min
    ,lio_max
    ,lio_avg
    ,pio_min
    ,pio_max
    ,pio_avg
    ,cnt
    ,abort_cnt
    ,qtext
    )
AS
SELECT a.uid
    ,- a.gid
    ,a.hashkey
    ,a.id
    ,a.sequence
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('e1', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('e2', b.TEXT) - charindex('e1', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('e2', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('e3', b.TEXT) - charindex('e2', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('e3', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('t1', b.TEXT) - charindex('e3', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('t1', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('t2', b.TEXT) - charindex('t1', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('t2', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('t3', b.TEXT) - charindex('t2', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('t3', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('l1', b.TEXT) - charindex('t3', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('l1', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('l2', b.TEXT) - charindex('l1', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('l2', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('l3', b.TEXT) - charindex('l2', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('l3', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('p1', b.TEXT) - charindex('l3', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('p1', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('p2', b.TEXT) - charindex('p1', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('p2', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('p3', b.TEXT) - charindex('p2', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('p3', b.TEXT) + 3, charindex('c', b.TEXT) - charindex('p3', b.TEXT) - 4))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('c', b.TEXT) + 2, charindex('ac', b.TEXT) - charindex('c', b.TEXT) - 3))
    ,convert(INT, substring(b.TEXT, charindex('ac', b.TEXT) + 3, char_length(b.TEXT) - charindex('ac', b.TEXT) - 2))
    ,a.TEXT
FROM sysqueryplans a
    ,sysqueryplans b
WHERE (a.type = 10)
    AND (b.type = 1000)
    AND (a.id = b.id)
    AND a.uid = b.uid
    AND a.gid = b.gid
```